# Is BT Guard active?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have followed the instructions on the [BT Guard wiki](https://wiki.btguard.com/index.php/CheckMyTorrentIP), but where they say that I should see an IP address (theirs)

[image: their image]

But I see none:

[image: I see none]

Now, if I saw my own IP Address, I would know that I have not connected correctly. But, when I see no IP address, I am confused - am I correctly using and connected to BT Guard or not?

Comment: It is not working based on "status updating" message

Comment: It will always have that status, even when updating. It is a torrent which never finishes downloading, just for testing